# "No default constructor exists " even though I don't need it

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

I'd like to ask as to why does my compilator say "No default constructor exists for class Object" even though I don't need it anywhere in that class.

I am supposed to NOT use a default constructor (it's explicitly said that I only need a parametrized one with parameter id, [full assignment can be found on this link](https://github.com/MrAntrophy/ICpp1/tree/master/Session03_HomeWork#session-3-task---inheritance))

I've tried to think of the reason why it needs default constructor but I just can't see it. Like, not even in header I need constructor for object.

I've been searching google too but it doesn't answer my question either, or if it does I just can't understand it and apply it for my example.

This is my Object.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef OBJECT_H
#define OBJECT_H
class Object
{
public:
    Object(int aId);
    virtual ~Object() {};
    int getId() const;
    double getX() const;
    double getY() const;
    void setX(double aX);
    void setY(double aY);
private:
    int id;
    double x;
    double y;
};

#endif //!OBJECT_H
```

This is my Object.cpp

```cpp
#include "Object.h"

Object::Object(int aId)
{
    this->id = aId;
}

int Object::getId() const
{
    return this->id;
}

double Object::getX() const
{
    return this->x;
}

double Object::getY() const
{
    return this->y;
}

void Object::setX(double aX)
{
    this->x = aX;
}

void Object::setY(double aY)
{
    this->y = aY;
}
```

This is the header file for the class that I am getting the error in

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef STATIC_OBJECT_H
#define STATIC_OBJECT_H

#include "Object.h"

enum class ObstacleType { Rock, SmallFlower, BigFlower };
class StaticObject : public Object {

public:
    StaticObject(int aId, ObstacleType aObstacleType);
    ObstacleType& getObstacleType();
private:
    ObstacleType obstacleType;
};


#endif // !STATIC_OBJECT_H
```

And here on the line 4 starting with a bracket I get the error saying "No default constructor exists in class Object" even though I don't need it there, even if I don't put anything in the block it keeps saying that.

```cpp
#include "StaticObject.h"

StaticObject::StaticObject(int aId, ObstacleType aObstacleType)
{   // <-- compilator error shows here
    Object* obj = new Object(aId);
    this->obstacleType = aObstacleType;
}

ObstacleType& StaticObject::getObstacleType() {
    return this->obstacleType;
}
```

Comment: The duplicate answers the mechanics. As a matter of design, though, remember **every constructor constructs all bases**. That's fundamental to type safety; you have to work really hard to create an object that hasn't been properly constructed. If the constructor doesn't explicitly construct the class' bases the compiler generates code that uses the default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your `StaticObject` constructor is not calling any non-default `Object` constructor, so the default constructor will be called for the base class, thus your current code *does* need a default `Object` constructor.